# Timer to get data from server every x minutes :iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, timer

In my iPhone app, i need to get data from server every 60 minutes, even if the app is in background. 
Is it possible to put a timer and method to call every 60 minutes in appdelegate ?

Comment: This question is only asking for a YES or NO answer. Very low quality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. You can get background privileges for certain things; GPS tracking, music players, Skype-type apps. You can also ask for extra time when backgrounded to complete tasks. The extra time won't be 60 minutes. But there's no way to "wake up" an app without user intervention.

You might want to set a local notification to have the user open the app every hour.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to request data in the way that you want to when the application is in the background.

If the data is only important to the user when the application is open, might I suggested polling the server for all data it has not downloaded when the user re-opens the application?

Otherwise, if you're hoping to do background calculations while the app is closed, I can't help you unfortunately.